# Can you really trust WhatsApp's end-to-end encryption?

Tags: encryption

I've seen many articles that actually trust WhatsApp's encryption and they may be right, but here is the thing that really makes me suspicious; all end-to-end encrypted apps I know, such as Telegram and Signal are blocked in China, but WhatsApp that is far more popular is not.

If China is not blocking this app in particular (and after seeing all those [chummy visits](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/mar/18/mark-zuckerberg-beijing-smog-jog-china-facebook-pollution) by Zuckerberg) I am a little wary that your data is really end-to-end encrypted without the possibility of Facebook to intervene.

Is there any way for anyone to assess without shadow of a doubt that WhatsApp encryption is really end-to-end encrypted like there is with Signal?